# The Gradient descent different between in Ng coursera and Michael A. Nielsen book

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I am learning the neural networking from NG machine learning course in `coursera` and the book neural networking and deep learning by Nielson. I have a little confusion about the understanding of the Gradient Descent. I see two different formals to update weight by the Gradient Descent between NG and Nielson.

from Nielson:

[the weight update formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VmWi.png)

[the chapter Two, section The backpropagation algorithm](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html)

from NG:

[the weight update formal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkbFi.png)

both of them are used to update weights after forwarding pass in the backpropagation algorithm. in Neil version, it seems there is a learning rating -η in NG version, it does not have any learning rating, and it more like the learning rating is +1.  I am very confused on this. is there anyone can help me to understand it?

Comment: Probably better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Are you sure NGs formule covers the parameter update? It seems to just handle the backpropagation

Comment: @Ben, thanks for reminding. you are right. I was wrong. NGs formula just sum the deltas and will get a mean and plus regularization to get the gradient. the different is ngs formula calculate gradient by passing all samples. neilson formula calculate gradient by each sample.  [more tails about NG](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/pjdBA/backpropagation-algorithm)

Comment: Ah, the latter is a different approach (stochastic gradient descent), useful for large datasets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NG formule you showed does not cover the parameter update, it is only covering calculation of the gradients.